# Ruby, combining items in arrays?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a method that outputs a varying number of arrays like so:

```
[["unidentified object", 50], ["person", 22], ["car", 55], ["SUV", 32], ["large_vehicle", 76]] 
[["unidentified object", 167], ["person", 104], ["car", 265], ["SUV", 129], ["large_vehicle", 355]] 
[["unidentified object", 1963], ["person", 413], ["car", 1962], ["SUV", 996], ["large_vehicle", 2027]] 
[["unidentified object", 1526], ["person", 373], ["car", 1560], ["SUV", 765], ["large_vehicle", 1706]] 
[["unidentified object", 1234], ["person", 316], ["car", 1705], ["SUV", 895], ["large_vehicle", 1712]]
```

However I'd really like to have a hash that has the totals of each item totalled across all the arrays, something like:

```
[{:class => "unidentified object", :count => 7234}, {:class => "person", :count => 5231}, {...}]
```

Does that make sense? I totally need to read up on how the array and hash methods work, but any tips would really help.

Comment: Your numbers expressing the totals are wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
data = [
  [["unidentified object", 50], ["person", 22], # ...
  # ...
]

pairs = data.flatten(1)
grouped_by_class = pairs.group_by(&:first)
output = grouped_by_class.map do |cls, list| 
  {:class => cls, :count => list.map(&:last).inject(&:+)}
end
```

Unless you have some good reason for wanting the output to be exactly like you describe it, I suggest going for something simpler like `{'unidentified object' => 7234, ...}`, you can get that as output with this code:

```
data.flatten(1).inject(Hash.new(0)) do |h, (cls, count)|
  h[cls] += count
  h
end
```

Comment: You could also do `data.flatten(1).each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(key, value), hash| hash[key] += value }`.

Comment: `#each_with_object` is also new in 1.9 (IIRC), but I agree that it's more readable than `#inject`.

Comment: The only thing I have against it is that it's the only (again, IIRC) `#each...` method that does not return the enumerable itself, e.g. `#each`, `#each_with_index`, etc. returns the object it was called on, but `#each_with_object` goes against that convention.

Comment: `each_cons` would be another one that comes to mind (it returns `nil`). And yes, `each_with_object` is new.

Comment: some minor details: 1) if you unpack in group_by why not in the map? it will be more clear 2) inject(&:+) -> inject(:+). It's faster.

Comment: `flatten(1)` in Ruby 1.8.7 will do tha same as in 1.9.1.

Comment: @fl00r: you're right, I though it was a Rails extension, but it's actually in 1.8.7, I'll remove the note. @tokland: good point, guess I wasn't thinking, I've changed both to use the `Symbol#to_proc` hack, for consistency. I know using blocks is faster, but the line with `#map` would be twice as long with it...

Answer (score 4):

Give your input as an array of arrays of arrays:

```
a = [
    [["unidentified object", 50], ["person", 22], ["car", 55], ["SUV", 32], ["large_vehicle", 76]],
    [["unidentified object", 167], ["person", 104], ["car", 265], ["SUV", 129], ["large_vehicle", 355]],
    [["unidentified object", 1963], ["person", 413], ["car", 1962], ["SUV", 996], ["large_vehicle", 2027]],
    [["unidentified object", 1526], ["person", 373], ["car", 1560], ["SUV", 765], ["large_vehicle", 1706]],
    [["unidentified object", 1234], ["person", 316], ["car", 1705], ["SUV", 895], ["large_vehicle", 1712]],
]
```

You can do a one liner:

```
x = a.flatten(1).inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h, p| h[p[0]] += p[1]; h }.map { |k, v| { :class => k, :count => v } }
```

Comment: Yours after `map` is better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
result = Hash.new
array.each do |pair|

  result[pair.first] = 0 unless result.has_key? pair.first
  result[pair.first]+= pair.last
end
```

Not quite the output you wanted, but "something like" it.

Comment: You can avoid `result[pair.first] = 0 unless result.has_key? pair.first` if you say `result = Hash.new(0)` (but careful with this form of `Hash.new` when the argument isn't a Fixnum).

Comment: +1 for mu is too short's comment. To elaborate on what it means, when you want the default value of a hash to be an immutable object such as `0`, you do it in parenthesis like `Hash.new(0)`. When you want a mutable object such as `[]`, you put it in a block like `Hash.new{[]}` because you need to generate it each time.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your output arrays are themselves in an iterable, you could do this:

```
result = {}

arrays.each do |arr|
  if result[arr[0]]
    result[arr[0]] += arr[1]
  else
    result[arr[0]] = arr[1]
  end
end
```

This would iterate through the output arrays, and assuming that the first element of each sub-array can be treated as a hash key, it would then sum up the values for each key if the key exists in results hash. If the key doesn't exist in the hash, then it is simply added to the results hash.

Hope this does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [[["unidentified object", 50], ["person", 22], ["car", 55], ["SUV", 32], ["large_vehicle", 76]],
[["unidentified object", 167], ["person", 104], ["car", 265], ["SUV", 129], ["large_vehicle", 355]], 
[["unidentified object", 1963], ["person", 413], ["car", 1962], ["SUV", 996], ["large_vehicle", 2027]], 
[["unidentified object", 1526], ["person", 373], ["car", 1560], ["SUV", 765], ["large_vehicle", 1706]],
[["unidentified object", 1234], ["person", 316], ["car", 1705], ["SUV", 895], ["large_vehicle", 1712]]]
```

In ruby1.9, the following `hash` will give you a more natural form than what you asked for, and is used as an intermediate form to give the `array`, which is your desired form.

```
hash = a.flatten(1).each_with_object(Hash.new(0)){|(k, v), h| h[k] += v}
array = hash.each_with_object([]){|(k, v), h| h.push({class: k, count: v})}
```

Here is a way to do it directly

```
a.flatten(1).group_by{|k, v| k}.map{|k, v| {class: k, count: v.inject(0){|n, (k, v)| n += v}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple incremental solution that will work in any reasonable version of Ruby...

```
@r = Hash.new 0
def merge a
  a.each { |(c, n)| @r[c] += n }
end

merge [["unidentified object", 50], ["person", 22], ["car", 55], ["SUV", 32], ["large_vehicle", 76]] 
merge [["unidentified object", 167], ["person", 104], ["car", 265], ["SUV", 129], ["large_vehicle", 355]] 
merge [["unidentified object", 1963], ["person", 413], ["car", 1962], ["SUV", 996], ["large_vehicle", 2027]] 
merge [["unidentified object", 1526], ["person", 373], ["car", 1560], ["SUV", 765], ["large_vehicle", 1706]] 
merge [["unidentified object", 1234], ["person", 316], ["car", 1705], ["SUV", 895], ["large_vehicle", 1712]]

p @r.map { |k, v| {:class => k, :count => v}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [
    [["unidentified object", 50], ["person", 22], ["car", 55], ["SUV", 32], ["large_vehicle", 76]],
    [["unidentified object", 167], ["person", 104], ["car", 265], ["SUV", 129], ["large_vehicle", 355]],
    [["unidentified object", 1963], ["person", 413], ["car", 1962], ["SUV", 996], ["large_vehicle", 2027]],
    [["unidentified object", 1526], ["person", 373], ["car", 1560], ["SUV", 765], ["large_vehicle", 1706]],
    [["unidentified object", 1234], ["person", 316], ["car", 1705], ["SUV", 895], ["large_vehicle", 1712]],
]
```

You can return quite easy such kind of a hash, which looks little more flexible, than an Array of Hashes:

```
data.flatten(1).inject({}){|h, a| h[a[0]] ||= 0; h[a[0]]+=a[1]; h}
#=> {"person"=>1228, "unidentified object"=>4940, "SUV"=>2817, "car"=>5547, "large_vehicle"=>5876}
```

Or, for your exact goal:

```
data.flatten(1).inject({}){|h, a| h[a[0]] ||= 0; h[a[0]]+=a[1]; h}.map{|k,v| {:class => k, :count => v}}
#=> [{:class=>"person", :count=>1228}, {:class=>"unidentified object", :count=>4940}, {:class=>"SUV", :count=>2817}, {:class=>"car", :count=>5547}, {:class=>"large_vehicle", :count=>5876}]
```

Comment: that is the same solution as @mu is too short with small difference. So +1 to @mu is too short